# Generic function to give occurrences of values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Have to build the first array with all items that occur at least once, the second array with items that occur at least twice and so on.

```
 var arr1 = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello","ABC", "Hello"];

 Expected output format:
 run1 = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC"] //Here first array with all items that occur at least once
 run2 = ["Hi", "Hello","ABC"]// Items occur twice
 run3 = ["Hi", "Hello"] // Items occur thrice
```

Have to design a Generic functionality to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below code......

```js
var arr1 = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello","ABC", "Hello"];

function findOccured(array, count)
{
        result = [];
        arr1.forEach(element => {
         if(arr1.filter(item => item == element).length >= count){result.push(element);}
        });
        return result;
}

run1 = Array.from(new Set(arr1));
run2 = Array.from(new Set(findOccured(arr1, 2)));
run3 = Array.from(new Set(findOccured(arr1, 3)));
console.log(run1);
console.log(run2);
console.log(run3);
```

[image: Output as expected :]

Answer (score 0):

Using Map and Array#reduce you could do something like this.

Map -> keep track of the element count

```js
const data = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello","ABC", "Hello"];
 
 const res = data.reduce(({counter,res},c)=>{

    counter.set(c, (counter.get(c)||0) + 1)
    const index = counter.get(c) - 1;

    if(!res[index]) res[index] = [];
    res[index].push(c);

    return {counter, res};
 }, {counter: new Map(), res: []}).res;
 
 console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrences of each item in the original array, then filter the results based on the occurrences' count.

```js
var arr1 = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello","ABC", "Hello"];
var run1 = [], run2 = [], run3 = []
var count = {};
arr1.forEach((x) => { 
   count[x] = ( count[x] || 0) + 1;
   if (count[x] > 0 && run1.indexOf(x) < 0) run1.push(x)
   if (count[x] > 1 && run2.indexOf(x) < 0) run2.push(x)
   if (count[x] > 2 && run3.indexOf(x) < 0) run3.push(x)
});
console.log(run1);
console.log(run2);
console.log(run3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `closure` to build a dynamic function. Then we can save the iteration for the next use.

```js
var arr1 = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello","ABC", "Hello"];

function buildSet() {
  const rsObj = arr1.reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc[item] = acc[item] || 0
   acc[item]++ 
   return acc
  }, {})
  
  return function(time) {
    return Object.entries(rsObj).reduce((acc, [name, count]) => {
      return count >= time ? acc.concat(name) : acc
    }, [])  
  }
}

const wordLeast = buildSet()

console.log(wordLeast(1))
console.log(wordLeast(2))
console.log(wordLeast(3))
```

Comment: Have to apply the above concept for this kind of object:
like have to make array for this obj
Run:{
"BC":{"ABC":"9","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"RC":{"ABC":"0","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"GB":{"ABC":"5","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CH":{"ABC":"150","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},
"BC":{"ABC":"9","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"RC":{"ABC":"0","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"GB":{"ABC":"5","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CH":{"ABC":"150","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},
"BC":{"ABC":"9","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"RC":{"ABC":"0","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CV":{"ABC":"50","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CH":{"ABC":"150","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},
"HT":{"ABC":"450","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""}};

Comment: @user11095631 so what is the expected output? You can make another question and show what you've done so far. We can help you solve what you stuck.

Comment: It should return like below:
 Run1: {"BC":{"ABC":"9","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"RC":{"ABC":"0","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"GB":{"ABC":"5","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CH":{"ABC":"150","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"RC":{"ABC":"0","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CV":{"ABC":"50","XYZ":[""],"HT":{"ABC":"450","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""}};
 Run2: {"BC":{"ABC":"9","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"RC":{"ABC":"0","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""}, "GB":{"ABC":"5","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CH":{"ABC":"150","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""}}; 
Run3: {"BC":{"ABC":"9","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""},"CH":{"ABC":"150","XYZ":[""],"MNO":""}};

Some how I'm not able to create new question!! help me

Comment: @user11095631 your first obj Run have wrong JSON format. because if the object has the same keys, only the last will used. So I am not sure `obj Run` is an object or a collection?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these combinations

```js
var arr1 = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello", "ABC", "Hi", "Hi", "Hello", "ABC", "Hello"];

function custom(arr1, cnt) {
  var groups = arr1.reduce(function(acc, e) {
    acc[e] = (e in acc ? acc[e] + 1 : 1);
    return acc
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(groups).filter(function(key) {
    return groups[key] >= cnt
  });
}
var once = custom(arr1, 1);
var twice = custom(arr1, 2);
var thrice = custom(arr1, 3);
console.log(once, twice, thrice);
```